# Please allow editing tag wikis on child metas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, tag-wiki

On child metas, [a few tag wikis are copied from the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66425/can-the-tag-wikis-for-the-mandatory-tags-and-moderator-only-tags-be-propagated-t). It's a good idea, because it helps to have tags that mostly mean the same thing on all meta sites. However…

- The set of copied tags is pretty small, leading to quite a bit of divergence. (What's the tag for discussing the topic delineation of a site? `scope`? `off-topic`? `on-topic`? `allowed-topics`? `on-topic-discussion`? `off-topic-discussion`? `on-topic-definition`? `off-topic-content`? `on-off-topic`? `on-topic-off-topic`? All of these exist on some meta, many metas use more than one, and that's not all of them.)
- There are issues that are unique to specific metas. For example, [language](/questions/tagged/language) is the #2 tag here, for an issue that doesn't exist on most sites.
- Some metas have specific needs. For example, it would be nice to have French translations of tag wikis on Meta too.

Please allow child metas to have their own tag wikis. Ideally, any tag on a child meta should automatically have its MSO tag wiki unless locally overridden. In other words, allow tag wiki edition on child metas, and show the MSO tag wiki if the local tag wiki is empty.

Comment: Good points. However, is the first bullet a completely different issue? I can't see the link with the editing of inherited tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is now implemented.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites/121066#121066)

Now tag wikis on meta sites can be edited, subject to the same reputation requirements as the main site (anyone can propose, 1500 rep for approval, 4000 rep to create without approval).